# How to set the login password for scrapyd

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I want to use scrapyd to manage my scrapy project.Scrapyd is deployed on the Ubuntu server,and I want to set the login password for scrapyd,I don't want anyone can call scrapyd's API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any user/login management in the documentation. 
The standards seem to be that only localhost can connect to scrapyd.

I think the only way is to use firewalling to prevent other users on the same machine to connect to scrapyd.